# how to install electron on windows 10

Tags: electron

I am trying to install electron on windows 10 but  not working.
My environment is Windows 10, x64, 16gb ram.
I have install updated version of nodeJS and npm .

My application root folder directory is ***c:\nodeP\app1***
and I tried following commands on the cmd

1. cd\
2. cd nodeP
3. cd app1
4. npm init
5. npm install electron-prebuilt --save dev
6. npm start

**main.js file**

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

app.on('ready', function () {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width : 500,
    height : 200
  });
});
```

But when I run the app it show me the error like this image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJTLI.png)

I could not find any solution in the internet which could guide me for windows 10. I found all tutorials for MAC and Linux.

I need to know if this electron app is only for these platforms or not. If it supports windows 10 please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think step 5 should include 'save-dev', not 'save dev', as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816384/unsupported-platform-for-inotify1-4-1-wanted-oslinux-archany).

Also, as of 7/17/2017, I think the name 'electron-prebuilt' is [deprecated](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt), 'electron' should be used instead.

However, as a complete Electron and Node newb, when I create a test app as described and try to run it from PowerShell on Windows 10 with 'Electron test1', I get this:

> The term 'Electron' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. [more]

If I cd to {project}\node_modules\electron\dist\, I can then do this to run Electron itself:

> .\electron.exe

...but that's much more awkward than the short form given in every doc I've seen.

It also doesn't run my test app, which I can do my dragging its main.js file onto the Electron app, but again that's more awkward than all the step-by-steps I've seen.

Please speak up if you know what I've got wrong here.