# How to solve "Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
**npm ERR!** code EBADPLATFORM
**npm ERR!** notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})

**npm ERR!** notsup Valid OS:    linux
**npm ERR!** notsup Valid Arch:  any
**npm ERR!** notsup Actual OS:   darwin
**npm ERR!** notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: @ Emad Emami, I have a Latest Version of node v6.11.4

Comment: it seem inotify support only < version 6 (NodeJS versions 0.10.x, 0.12.x, 4.x.x, 5.x.x and IO.js 1.x, 2.x, 3.x are currently supported and tested.)

Comment: node-inotify only supports linux: https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify/blob/v1.4.2/package.json#L19-L21

Comment: Has anyone figured this out. I have the same issue and don't know how to fix this either. I got a project from another group and I get this error when I run the npm install dev command. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816384/unsupported-platform-for-inotify1-4-1-wanted-oslinux-archany)

Answer (score 5):

This is possibly due to the dev package which gets installed with npm and this problem generally occurs with Mac OS.

Run the below command to remove the dev package.

```
npm uninstall dev --save
```

I hope I'm able to help with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using nom, but I tried with Yarn, it worked.

```
$ npm i dev jest
  npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
  npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
  npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
  npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux
  npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
  npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
  npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

But then I tried with yarn

```
$ yarn add --dev jest
```

This might not have fix the problem with npm but it fixed this error for me

Comment: You were trying to install the `dev` package.

Answer (score 1):

Below command worked for me.

```
sudo npm -g uninstall dev --save
```

More details on uninstalling npm package can be found here : [How to uninstall npm modules in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

don't forgot `--` before `dev` when you are using yarn as a package manager

Answer (score 0):

In case you're a complete idiot (like me), make sure you're actually typing `npm add --save-dev` and NOT `npm add --save=dev`. The latter will try to install the `dev` package, which directly depends on `inotify`.