# Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.6 on Mac while npm install

Tags: reactjs, macos, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to set up a project for react. however, while I run npm install, it throws this error:

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.6: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Apparently, It looks like this library is not supported on my mac. I hope some workaround can resolve this issue instead of removing this library.
kindly suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: find another library for MacOS

Comment: @KetZoomer actually this is one of the dependencies of some other library. can't figure out any other option

Comment: have you checked that you're not accidentally trying to install the `dev` package? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816384/unsupported-platform-for-inotify1-4-1-wanted-oslinux-archany

Comment: @adamgy. I tried that too. but it didn't work.

Comment: @Archit have you found a solution by chance? I'm getting this error both on macOS and on a Windows 10 VM I have installed thru Parallels...

Comment: oooh this magically worked for me: npm uninstall dev --save

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59159117/10431460

Simply running this fixed the issue for me:

```
npm uninstall dev --save
```