# EBADPLATFORM - Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2

Tags: bootstrap-4, gulp-sass

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux

npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any

npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32

npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-14T06_22_08_427Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816384/unsupported-platform-for-inotify1-4-1-wanted-oslinux-archany)

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened on Windows 10 (x64) while trying:

```
 npm install dev
```

It has **inotify** as a dependency which itself works on *Linux* only.
It's sad so many packages depend on **dev** which means these can't be cross-platform anymore.

I was able to remove **dev** from dependencies in **package.json** and still run the package I was interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading npm by running `npm install npm@3.10.7 --force`, worked for me !